# Kill command line process and restart if STDOUT changes to what I'm looking for?

Tags: regex, command-line, process, stdout, kill

I have a question - I'm running a process from the command line that has some problem and poops out every few hours or so. While I'm looking into the issue, I'd like to spawn the process from something that monitors STOUT for certain string/regex and kills and restarts the process if it outputs something that indicates that it's broken.

I know I could do this the vanilla way by rolling my own Python/Ruby script but I was wondering if there's any nifty tools I can use to make this a bit cleaner? This is on Windows but I have cygwin in case the answer involves a unix command line process.

Answer (score 1):

program | grep CRASH_STRING | xargs -l 1 sh -c 'killall program && program'

Well, that will do it once. I'm not sure how to make that work in a loop. I thought about it some more, and it can probably be done by redirecting stdout to a named pipe. But the shell script will probably end up more unwieldy than writing a watchdog in a scripting language.

But the idea with a pipe is something like this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
program > /tmp/fifo&
while :
do
grep "CRASH_STRING" /tmp/fifo | xargs -l 1 sh -c 'killall program && program > /tmp/fifo&'
done
```

Comment: Nice idea, but you're likely to run into buffering problems with that approach; `grep` directed into a pipe – named or otherwise – doesn't produce output until it's got a whole buffer full or an EOF. The second one won't work at all; it won't start the program until after the program crashes, even leaving aside buffering…

Comment: Are you sure about the buffering? If it's stdout being written to the pipe, then it should be getting flushed with each newline.

You're right about the second one being broken, it wouldn't even ever launch the first time... 

I tried fixing it up now. In conclusion, shell is a terrible tool for this problem, definitely use python or ruby.

Comment: yes, stdout is _not_ linebuffered by default (std::err is unbuffered by default). stdout is normally flushed on demand, or on the first poll for input on stdin. Primitives in many language silently include the explicit flush at the end of lines

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'll probably go the Ruby/Python way